# Yup validation: Remove or alter certain schema key/value pairs

Tags: yup

First and foremost - love the lib, thank you for making this!

I have a question about a form of conditional validation (I have looked at other q/answers, and I don't really think that it applies here)

I have a form with nested values as such (its much larger, with 5 more entries at the same level as `entry1` and 5 to 10 more sublevels of `entryXsubX`, with some that have a lot more complex validations):

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({ 
  entry1: yup.object().shape({
    entry1sub1: yup.string().required(),
    entry1sub2: yup.string().required()
  })
})
```

and im trying to do something to make `entry1.entry1sub2` optional;
trying to do

```js
schema.concat(yup.object().shape({
  entry1: yup.object().shape({
    entry1sub2: yup.string().nullable().notRequired()
  })
}))
```

doesnt seem to work, as it just overrides `entry1` where `entry1sub1` stops existing.

is there a way to do this aside from conditionally removing the validations?

`entry1sub2: entry1sub2optional ? yup.string().nullable() : yup.string().required()`

because I would have to do it to all the entries, and as stated, there are many of them there, and I wanted to have the possibility to be able to make any entry optional

thank you if you took the time to read! ^_^